# How does the spring loaded pogo pin retain its compressed position?

Tags: pcb, connector, testing, power-connector, pogo-pins

As per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_pin)

> Pogo pins are used for their improved durability over other electrical contacts, and the resilience of their electrical connection to mechanical shock and vibration.

I am not able to figure out how the compressed position of a pogo contact is retained. Unless you apply a significant force external (against the spring,)  wouldn't it try to release the plunger back?
[image]

Edit: I see the test PCB (black) is screwed down to test jig PCB( green). So the advantage essentially I see here is even if the pogo pins lengths are slightly different, the spring ensures the contact for all pins.

But I can appreciate this logic only if pogo pins are supposed to be connected to test points.

How is it useful for a connector and socket arrangement? I see [manufacturers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNrv63yltlI) claiming it being useful in many electronic appliances. If there is a socket and pin connection, why would anyone prefer a retractable 'soft' pin over a solid pin?

[image]

Comment: If they're not broken, they don't retain their position.

Comment: "apply a significant force external (against the spring,)" ... well, yes - that's exactly what happens. The pin gets pressed against another contact surface, and they're held together by some other mechanical means, causing the spring to compress.

Comment: Maybe you can explain how you think pogo pins are supposed to function so we can see where your misconception lies? Hit the [edit] link below your question ...

Comment: @Transistor: yes I edited the question for clarity,

Comment: @MOSFET I'd add that regrettably, they break: particularly when used for recharging etc. rather than for occasional test or programming purposes. I don't know whether this is in any way due to their being soldered in (spring is exposed to soldering temperature) rather than socketed.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd when used other than on PCBs, they may be held in place by grubscrews.  Overtightening is an issue then (something I'll have to beware of in a few weeks, assembling a test fixture for laser diodes, into which I designed a 4-pogo-pin connection)

Comment: @ChrisH I know, they /might/. But equally they might be relying on the wight of something paced in a charging cradle or on a charging base, where not only is the pressure erratic but potentially-contaminated contacts are placed together without a wiping action: both are harbingers of premature failure.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd yes, I was just adding a non-soldered failure mode (mine, BTW) will be screwed together for thermal contact, so plenty of pressure, and in a fairly clean lab. It's inspired by the interlock circuit on some laser systems I've used

Answer (score 8):

> How is it useful for a connector and socket arrangement?

I'll give just one:

[image]

*Figure 1. First-generation MagSafe connector by Apple. Image source: [MagSafe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagSafe).*

The MagSafe connecor uses pogo pins for the electrical contacts and the peripheral magnet to protect the pins and hold it in place against the device contact pads. This connector has the advantage that it can be disconnected without damage by pulling the cable at any angle (tripping over the power lead, for example). A pin and socket type can only be disconnected with a pull close to in-line with the pin axis.

Answer (score 6):

> I am not able to figure out how the compressed position of a pogo contact is retained. Unless you apply a significant force external (against the spring,) wouldn't it try to release the plunger back?

Its compressed position is retained by exerting an opposing force on whatever is making contact with the pin - you can't just rest the contact point on top of a pin and expect things to work.

Regarding "*significant force*" - one pin alone is often negligible, but the force increases as you add more.

---

Pogo pins are used for all sorts of connections - from batteries and other quick connect systems through to test jigs.

Without a movable "head", in any situation where the two halves don't have *perfect* / *infinitesimal* tolerances (and thus are extremely expensive to produce) you'll find that some points don't make contact due to high or low points. Allowing the head to move means that the tolerances can grow (often significantly) with a good connection still being made. Of course, you can't just let the head move freely, as it'll fall due to gravity, so a spring is used to keep it "up", but it allows movement to absorb these differences.

The spring also provides force between the contact points - it's actually possible to have two conductors physically touching but not making a good electrical connection (or potentially any connection at all - see [Wetting current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetting_current)). Gravity alone is fairly weak, and sometimes can't penetrate the oxidie layer by itself. You can often see this effect if you're *very* gentle with multimeter / scope probes - we don't just rest probes on the test point, we apply some pressure.

To summarise, compression is key for two reasons - compliance and connectivity. Look at test jigs, and you'll see that the device under test is actively "pushed" into the bed of nails.

See Adafruit's "[*How to Build a Test Jig*](https://learn.adafruit.com/how-to-build-a-testing-fixture/solder-pogo-pins)" writeup, and the "[*Toggle Clamp*](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2457)" they carry... what a good video!

With some test jigs that have a larger pin count, you actually need to be very careful about applying the opposing force - if you just push the corners down, the PCB may flex, and this can be problematic for things like solder joints. The force from a cluster of pogo pins can also add up significantly, exacerbating the situation.

---

edit:

> But I can appreciate this logic only if pogo pins are supposed to be connected to test points.
>
> How is it useful for a connector and socket arrangement? I see manufacturers claiming it being useful in many electronic appliances. If there is a socket and pin connection, why would anyone prefer a retractable 'soft' pin over a solid pin?

I'm confused - you've linked to a video that outlines many advantages and usage scenarios.

It's not so much that the pins are "*retractable*" (which would suggest they can be stowed or put away), but rather that they will A) exert their own force, and B) conform to a non-uniform or ill-defined mating position.

The MagSafe connector is one very well known example which even has the "pogo pin" appearance, but if you have a smart watch, take a look at the charging connection.

Also, remember that spring-loaded contacts are used extensively all over the place - in fact most connectors aren't just "*a solid pin*" as you suggest, but have at least one spring-loaded component in the connection. Even mostly-permanent internal connections regularly use sprung contacts (e.g: between a phone's mainboard and an LDS antenna, speaker, etc...). The only good example of non-sprung connections I can think of are where either a nut and bolt are used (e.g: cat battery terminals), or press-fit connectors or teminals (i.e: pushing a pin through a hole that is notionally "*too small*")

Answer (score 3):

Four ways the pogo pin could retain its (loaded) position. All fail modes except last:

- Perfectly axial mechanical overload: The inner "can" flares out and interferes with the outer shell. Friction between the inner flared rim and the inner surface of the outer shell create retention.
- Off-axis mechanical overload: The inner can buckles causing interference with the outer shell due to the deformation of the metal. Friction maintains the retention.
- The pin is subject to excessive shear force: The inner can, outer shell, or both deform laterally and no longer maintain a sliding fit. The pin doesn't pogo back to its original (unloaded) state, not because of friction, but because it is now jammed in pressed (bent) state.
- Mating parts are defective from manufacturer: Spring too weak or diameters out of tolerance causing unintended interference fit.

Answer (score 2):

> I see manufacturers claiming it being useful in many electronic appliances.

One category of use cases would be electrical contacts for devices that can be placed into a charging cradle.  And, of course, removed from the cradle.

Examples: Mobile radio devices, hand-held barcode scanners at retail store cash registers or in warehouses, etc.

Comment: I replaced some pins in a couple of expensive bedside lamps owned by friends because the springs had worn out. Lousy design on multiple counts.